# Unable to Connect to sonarqube from azure devops

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, devops

I'm unable to connect to the sonarcube server(localhost:9000) from Azure Devops(dev.azure.com)

The following is the error log:

```
[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":9000}
```

I've Authenticated it by generating token in Sonarqube and providing the credentials in dev.azure.

Comment: Where are you testing this? From a Build to SonarQube? Or from the SonarQube server itself and connecting to Azure DevOps? Is your agent running on the same server as SonarQube?

Comment: @RobBos - I am facing the same issue, I have configured sonar qube locally and trying to hit it from devops azure and getting the above error

Comment: It seems like the Azure DevOps agent cannot find the SonarQube server. Are both running on the same machine? Otherwise you need to configure the SonarQube service endpoint with its external IP and URL.